# What does "shall Michael stand up" mean in Daniel 12:1?

Tags: daniel

Daniel 12:1

> And at that time shall Michael stand up, the great prince who standeth for the children of thy people; and there shall be a time of trouble, such as never was since there was a nation even to that same time: and at that time thy people shall be delivered, every one that shall be found written in the book.

Does "shall Michael stand up" mean Michael will rule as king?

Comment: Over on the right of the page here, under "Related", and at the bottom is my Q., which I also answered. If not so much the Q., then maybe the Q., and A., together, answers your Q??

Comment: The words indicate that Michael shall stand up. What exactly is not clear to you ? The text expresses two separate concepts : stand up and stand for.

Answer (score 2):

Although Michael is traditionally understood to be an archangel, in the Book of Daniel itself his status is not immediately clear. His description and activities are a mainstay of angelology. The first mention of Michael is in Daniel 10:5-21 where a powerful heavenly being describes him as one of the "chief princes" and specifically as "your prince," who plays an important role in defeating the Persians and then the Greeks:

Daniel 10:5, 6, 12, 13, 20, 21 NABRE

> <sup>**5**</sup> I saw a man dressed in linen with a belt of fine gold around his waist. <sup>**6**</sup> His body was like chrysolite, his face shone like lightning, his eyes were like fiery torches, his arms and feet looked like burnished bronze, and the sound of his voice was like the roar of a multitude... <sup>**12**</sup> “Do not fear, Daniel,” he continued... your prayer was heard. Because of it I started out, <sup>**13**</sup> but the prince of the kingdom of Persia stood in my way for twenty-one days, until finally Michael, one of the chief princes, came to help me... <sup>**20**</sup> When I leave, the prince of Greece will come; <sup>**21**</sup> but I shall tell you what is written in the book of truth. No one supports me against these except Michael, your prince.

Because a heavenly being as described in vs. 5 has no need of aid from earthly princes, interpreters usually understand this to mean that Michael was the angelic guardian (patron saint) of Israel. Persia and Greece also apparently have such guardians. The heavenly being whom Michael aids must be either God himself and/or the angel of the Lord. Michael appears again in chapter 12, apparently describing the time of the resurrection:

Daniel 12:1, 2 NABRE

> <sup>**1**</sup> At that time there shall arise Michael, the great prince, guardian of your people; It shall be a time unsurpassed in distress since the nation began until that time. At that time your people shall escape, everyone who is found written in the book. <sup>**2**</sup> Many of those who sleep in the dust of the earth shall awake; Some to everlasting life, others to reproach and everlasting disgrace.

To summarize, Michael first appears as a "chief prince" who helps the powerful heavenly being (probably the angel of the Lord) prevail over the "prince" of Persia. Once the angel of the Lord withdraws, the "prince" of Greece will arise, and once again Michael ("your prince") will come to help overcome him.  Michael will arise one more in the day of judgment.

**Conclusion**: In the Book of Daniel, Michael is a non-material being who protects Israel against other such beings that champion the cause of Israel's pagan rulers, namely Persia and Greece. That he shall "stand up" means that he will rise, not that he will rule as a king.

Comment: Totally agree with your conclusion. Whenever the "AOTL" is mentioned in the OT, I myself, lean towards the "pre incarnate" Jesus. I think that, at least when considering **Daniel 10**, the AOTL, being aided by the chief angel, and therefore Archangel, Michael, is again the angel Gabriel, as per previous chapters. Michael does indeed stand up in the day of judgement, but, as per my "related Q and A", I think **Daniel 12:1** relates to a 1st Century *rise* of Michael, who was there *standing* for the truly faithful to God, Israelites, at the time of the "great distress" surrounding 70 AD. + 1.